# Why is MySQL giving me this 1064-error on ISNULL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

MySQL gives me following error code, and I don't get it fixed.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SECOND),'9999-12-31 00:00:00')       FROM     STARTDATES AS S2       WHERE    S1' at line 15

Seems that 2nd ISNULL is not possible.

```
CREATE VIEW HUB1_VERSIONS AS
WITH STARTDATES (HUB_ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, BUSINESS_KEY) AS (
    SELECT  HUB1.HUB_ID, SATELLITES.STARTDATE, SATELLITES.ENDDATE, HUB1.BUSINESS_KEY
    FROM    HUB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT   HUB_ID, META_LOAD_DTS AS STARTDATE, META_LOAD_END_DTS AS ENDDATE
             FROM     HUB1_SATELLITE1
             UNION
             SELECT   HUB_ID, META_LOAD_DTS, META_LOAD_END_DTS
             FROM     HUB1_SATELLITE2) AS SATELLITES
             ON HUB1.HUB_ID = SATELLITES.HUB_ID)
SELECT  DISTINCT HUB_ID, STARTDATE,
        CASE WHEN ENDDATE_NEW <= ENDDATE_OLD THEN ENDDATE_NEW ELSE ENDDATE_OLD END AS ENDDATE, BUSINESS_KEY
FROM    (SELECT  S1.HUB_ID, ISNULL(S1.STARTDATE,'1900-01-01 00:00:00') AS STARTDATE,
                (SELECT   ISNULL(MIN(STARTDATE - '1' SECOND),'9999-12-31 00:00:00')
                 FROM     STARTDATES AS S2
                 WHERE    S1.HUB_ID = S2.HUB_ID
                 AND      S1.STARTDATE < S2.STARTDATE) AS ENDDATE_NEW,
                 ISNULL(S1.ENDDATE,'9999-12-31 00:00:00') AS ENDDATE_OLD,
                 S1.BUSINESS_KEY
        FROM     STARTDATES AS S1) AS S3
```

Here are the tables (tab-separated)

```
HUB_ID  BUSINESS_KEY    META_LOAD_DTS   META_SOURCE
1   b1  2012-06-01 00:00:00 Demo
2   b2  2011-03-20 00:00:00 Demo
3   b3  2013-11-22 00:00:00 Demo
4   b4  2013-09-09 00:00:00 Demo
-1  Unknown 1900-01-01 00:00:00 Repository
-2  N.a.    1900-01-01 00:00:00 Repository

HUB_ID  BUSINESS_KEY    META_LOAD_DTS   META_SOURCE
5   b5  2012-06-01 00:00:00 Demo
6   b6  2011-03-20 00:00:00 Demo
7   b7  2013-11-22 00:00:00 Demo
-1  Unknown 1900-01-01 00:00:00 Repository
-2  N.a.HUB3    1900-01-01 00:00:00 Repository

HUB_ID  BUSINESS_KEY    META_LOAD_DTS   META_SOURCE
5       b5              2012-06-01 00:00:00 Demo
6       b6              2011-03-20 00:00:00 Demo
7       b7              2013-11-22 00:00:00 Demo
-1      Unknown1900-01-01 00:00:00  Repository
-2      N.a.HUB31900-01-01 00:00:00 Repository
```

Comment: `STARTDATE - '1' SECOND` should be `STARTDATE - INTERVAL 1 SECOND`.

Comment: this did the trick!! Tnx a lot GMB!

Comment: You might want to mark the answer from @GMB as 'accepted'.